# Summation of big oh terms

Tags: asymptotics

I read about asymptotic notation .I understood the limit definition of big oh notation.But while going about calculating O(1)+O(2)+.......…..+O(n),the sum comes out to be O(n ^2).Can anyone explain the same?

Comment: What is $1+2+...+n$?

Comment: You would need to describe the situation more precisely. In the current form it is not quite clear what is meant. Actually there might be some imprecision there. In particular O(2) is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that $O(c) = O(1)$ where $c$ is any constant, I think your concern is this: if $f(n) = O(n)$ and if $$g(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$$
then why is it true that $g(n) = O(n^2)$?

It is misleading to write something like $$g(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n O(i).$$
We do not view each particular instance of $f(i)$ as being $O(i)$; the statement $f(n) = O(n)$ is a statement about $f$ as a function of $n$, not about $f$ at any particular value.

So how do we go about proving that $g(n) = O(n^2)$? 
Well, because $f$ is $O(n)$, there exist constants $C$ and $n_0$ such that $|f(n)| \ge Cn$ for all $n \ge n_0$. 
So for $n \ge n_0$, we split the sum and use the triangle inequality to approximate:
$$|g(n)| \le \sum_{i=1}^{n_0-1} |f(i)| + \sum_{i=n_0}^n |f(i)| \le C' + \sum_{i=n_0}^n Ci.\tag{1}$$
Here $C'$ is just the constant value of the first $n_0$ terms. 
We're allowed to be very loose in our estimates, so in the second sum in (1) we'll throw back in the numbers from $1$ to $n_0-1$ to get an even bigger bound: 
$$|g(n)| \le C' + C \sum_{i=1}^n i = C' + \frac{Cn(n+1)}{2}.\tag{2}$$
It should be clear now that the right hand side of (2) is $O(n^2)$, by which I mean it is bounded by a constant multiple of $n^2$. Indeed, $$C' + \frac{C}{2}(n(n+1)) = C' + \frac{C}{2}(n^2 + n) \le C'n^2 + \frac{C}{2}(n^2 + n^2) = (C' + C)n^2.$$